# pause jquery jPlayer when another video is clicked on page

Tags: jquery, jplayer

i have a background music playing on all pages (jPlayer) and i need to pause it when another embeded video is clicked/played on post or page or  sidebar
though this code doesn't seem to work:

```
<script>
//pauses jplayer
var selectors = [
        "iframe[src^='http://player.vimeo.com']", 
        "iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']", 
        "iframe[src^='https://www.youtube.com']", 
        "iframe[src^='http://www.kickstarter.com']", 
        "object", 
        "embed"
      ];
  $selectors.click(function() {
  $.jPlayer.pause();
});
</script>
```

what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    // Find all videos
    var selectors = [
        "iframe[src^='http://player.vimeo.com']", 
        "iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']", 
        "iframe[src^='https://www.youtube.com']", 
        "iframe[src^='http://www.kickstarter.com']", 
        "object", 
        "embed"
      ];
        // The element that is fluid width
    var $allVideos = $(this).find(selectors.join(','));
    // Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
        $allVideos.hover(function(){
            $.jPlayer.pause(); 
        });
});
```

works on hover - click is complicated as for different players  API